# How to show custom error page in ServiceStack

Tags: exception, razor, view, servicestack

I have read through [Error Handling](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling), ServiceStack_Succinctly.pdf, ServiceStack 4 Cookbook and various SO questions and am still unable to get the following working.

I want a way to show my own "pretty" error page for any exception that is thrown in any of my services. If any exception is thrown I want to take the user to a friendly page that shows the error message without any information that "mere mortals" won't understand.

Ideally I want this while maintaining typed responses on my service requests, i.e. ***not***

```
public object Get(GetOrder request)
{ 
   return new GetOrderResponse()
             {
               ...
             }
}
```

but rather

```
public GetOrderResponse Get(GetOrder request)
{ 
   return new GetOrderResponse()
             {
               ...
             }
}
```

I'd appreciate guidance on how to get this working or an example where this is done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the options for [Fallback Error Pages](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling#fallback-error-pages) e.g. you can display an `/oops.cshtml` Razor page with:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat()); //Register ServiceStack.Razor Plugin

    this.GlobalHtmlErrorHttpHandler = new RazorHandler("/oops"),
}
```

Or for more fine-grained control, use `IAppHost.CustomHttpHandlers` for specifying custom HttpHandlers to use with specific error status codes, e.g.:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    this.CustomHttpHandlers[HttpStatusCode.NotFound] = 
        new RazorHandler("/notfound");
    this.CustomHttpHandlers[HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized] = 
        new RazorHandler("/login");
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. I never see my "error" page. It is called Error.cshtml and it is in the root of my service, not in the Views folder. If I put "public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }" on my response DTO the "Order" page is shown as expected and as per the documentation - I have added code to check the ResponseStatus. If I remove the property however I get the standard SS json page and not the error page which is what I'd expect.

Comment: @GerhardWessels ok looks like it wasn't falling back to the Global Html ErrorHandler in Service Exceptions, it should do now [from this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/b2f24c0cdf2a0e2bd5fc5e09f8a184566f046475) which is available from v4.0.47 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).